# Magento 2.3 filter product enable but showing disable also

Tags: product, magento2.3, filter

Filter with **simple product** and status **enable** but showing disable also
please look at the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Open that disabled product and check if the product is disabled on store view level

Comment: @RakeshVarma yes it's disabled on store view level

Comment: @vivek you may have a third party module creating a Status attribute that is different to the bundled Status attribute, that is causing a conflict in the SQL of the search results... Otherwise you'd need to look into how the reloadData function at the source Knockout Component works.. Which is never fun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple store view then,

Edit the product & change the store view.

If "**Enable Product**" is different than main store view then, it's occur.

So you can check "**Use Default Value**" for "**Enable Product**" attribute and save products.

Comment: thank you so much. it's work for me

Answer (score 0):

**So you can check "Use Default Value" for "Enable Product" attribute and save products.**
I did not get this suggestion. I'm having the same issue.
Can you please explain a bit more about this? @Vivek @Rohan Hapani